# Как лучше передавать объекты в приложениях клиент-сервер?

Tags: java-ee, javascript, java, сервер

Для взаимодействия клиента и сервера я использую вебсокеты. Сервер на java, клиент на javascript. Для передачи данных о каком-то объекте я передаю его параметры в обычной строке разделенной спецсимволами и получатель парсит полученную строчку. Подозреваю, что есть способ более правильный, легкий и безопасный.
Пробовал с сервера посылать сразу объект. Однако, клиент как будто ничего не получает.

Сервер:

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(data);
```

Клиент:

```
function onMessage(event) { 
    var arr = event.data;
    arr[0] = event.data[0];
    arr[1] = event.data[1];
    arr[2] = event.data[2];
document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML 
    += '<br />' + " id " + arr[0] 
    + " position " + arr[1] +" , " + arr[2] ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чем не устроил json?